# WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '75' and signal 'null' -How to resolve the issue

Tags: ios, automation, appium, ios-simulator, cucumber-java

s already started! [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '75' and signal 'null' [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code 'null' and signal 'SIGTERM'

Am getting this error on parallel execution via running Simulators . IF am running with individual Simulator it works fine and also if am running cross platform parallel like  emulator and simulator is working fine

Issue with via multiple instance of simulator .could you please help me in resolving this issue because mostly am in IOS automation and I could require running scripts with multiple simulator or real devices  using cucumber framework FYI

Comment: Did you run them on different appium server ports and WDA ports for every device?

Comment: please format your code(error log) with code fences to make the code readable. Goodluck 

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.